# Why is $X_{n-k,n}$ a good estimator for $U(\frac{n}{k})$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm learning about Extreme Value Theory. In my class we're discussing the $U(t)$-tail quantile which has the following definition:

*For a distribution function $F$, the tail quantile function $U(t)$ is defined such that*
$$
P(X> U(t) ) = 1 - F(U(t)) = \frac{1}{t}, \,t\geq 1
$$
Suppose that you have a sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ from distribution function $F$. Estimation of $U(\frac{1}{p})$ is based on the following result:

*For $F\in D(G_\gamma)$, for $\gamma>0$, iff*
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{U(tx)}{U(t)} = x^\gamma,
$$
$U(tx)\approx U(t)x^\gamma$. Now let $tx = \frac{1}{p}$, and $t = \frac{n}{k}$, where $k$ is a large integer but much smaller than $n$. We then have
$$
U\bigl(\frac1p \bigr) \approx U\bigl(\frac{n}{k} \bigr)\bigl( \frac{k}{np}\bigr)^\gamma
$$
I think that I understand all this. Now comes the part that I'm having trouble with to grasp:

*Let $X_{1,n}, \ldots, X_{n,n}$ be the order statistics of the sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. $U(\frac{n}{k})$ can be estimated by the empirical quantile $X_{n-k,n}$. (Why is this a good estimator? Think about the empirical distribution function $\hat{F}(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n I(X_i\leq x).)$*

**Question:** Why is $X_{n-k,n}$ a good estimator for $U(\frac{n}{k})$?

Intuitively I understand that it might would be a good estimator, since $P\bigl( X > U(\frac1p) \bigr) = p$ so that $U\bigl(\frac1p \bigr) = x_{1 -p}$. Hence you would get that $P\bigl( X > U(\frac{n}{k}) \bigr) = \frac{k}{n}$ and $U(\frac{n}{k}) = x_{1 - k/n}$. A sensible estimator for $x_{1 - k/n}$ would then be $X_{n-k, n}$.

I don't find this satisfying though, especially since I supposedly have to think about the empirical distribution function to understand why this would be a good estimator.

Comment: Good estimator is so vague that your intuitive understanding is a good enough answer to the question. If there was a hard criterion about what would count as a good estimator (unbiasedness, consistency, or something else), then one could formulate a precise answer.